# Activity + Tabs

Tags: java, android, tab

Вопрос собственно в следующем. Поскольку TabActivity (tab контент activity) является устаревшим, какие альтернативы есть?
FragmentActivity (не подходит, поскольку контент Fragment)

Comment: для чего он Вам нужен? может `Activity` подойдет?

Comment: Приложение будем типа инстаграма, но большей воложенности.

Answer (score 1):

[ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)
Он пришел на замену сразу двум вещам: Galerry и TabActivity

Answer (score 0):

Кроме `ViewPager` можно использовать `FragmentTabHost`.

Пример использования - https://github.com/akadatsky/FragmentTabHostSample